# Do something using Dockerfile RUN but ignore errors

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, dockerfile

I think I want to have Docker RUN something which I know will fail, but then use a repair to fix it up, i.e.

```
RUN dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_arm64.deb
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt fix-broken install
```

It seems that `apt` recognises that `wkhtmltox` failed to install due to missing packages and is then able to install them all. ...I think.

Anyway, even trying this means allowing the Docker build to continue upon a bad exit code.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
RUN dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_arm64.deb || true
RUN apt-get update || true
RUN apt fix-broken install || true
```

Comment: the `s1 || s2` means run `s1` and if that fails, run `s2`.

Comment: Combining these into a single `RUN` statement might make sense, as you can then just combine them with `;` which basically hides the exit code from all commands except the last from Docker.

Answer (score 1):

You may really want a few improvements in addition to just getting this working!

- verify `dpkg` successfully brought in the package
- use `apt-get` instead of `apt` to avoid the stable interface warning
- run all your `apt` commands in the same block with `clean` at the end to reduce container size

```
# NOTE dpkg -i exits nonzero due to missing dependencies
RUN dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_arm64.deb ; \
    dpkg -l | grep wkhtmltox
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -f install && \
    apt-get clean
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I will keep the official answer as Antonio's because I guess it's the purer answer to the original question.